# Как обновить несколько записей одного поля?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

**Имеется**
1. Таблица - table
2. Поля:
- id;
- pole_1;
- pole_2;
- pole_3;
3. Таблица содержит 9-ть записей.

Можно ли обновить записи "pole_2" для "id" > 3 одним запросом?
Или нужно для каждой записи делать отдельный запрос?
**Для id = 4**

```
update table 
set  
 `pole_2` = 'zapis_4_izm_1' 
 where id = 4
```

**Для id = 5**

```
update table 
set  
 `pole_2` = 'zapis_5_izm_2' 
 where id = 5
```

и т.д.

Значение записи "zapis_4_izm_1", "zapis_5_izm_2" приведены в условном виде.
По факту все записи `pole_2` будут разные и не будут иметь прослеживаемой тенденции.

**Вопрос.**
Как обновить записи "pole_2" для "id" > 3 одним запросом ?
Т.е. имеем набор разных не повторяющихся записей для поля "pole_2".
Данные поступают из парсера.
Соответствие между значениями и id обновляемых записей устанавливается по порядку от указанного id в запросе..
Указываем в запросе, что нужно обновить все записи поля "pole_2" у которых "id" > 3.
Вставляем в запрос набор данных.
Выполняем запрос.

Comment: А что если id не хватит для входных данных или будут пропуски в id или будут лишние id, остающиеся без данных. почему требование именно id>3, а не текой-то id такие то данные ?

Comment: @Mike Да вроде продумал эту ситуацию... Всё должно быть нормально...Хотя практика покажет

Answer (score 3):

```
update `table`
set pole_2 = CONCAT('zapis_',id,'_izm_',id-3)
where id IN (4,5)
```

Comment: Немного не так. Внёс изменения в вопрос. Цитирую `Значение записи "zapis_4_izm_1", "zapis_5_izm_2" приведены в условном виде. По факту все записи pole_2 будут разные и не будут иметь прослеживаемой тенденции.`  `Т.е. имеем набор разных не повторяющихся записей для поля "pole_2".
Указываем в запросе, что нужно обновить все записи поля "pole_2" у которых "id" > 3.
Вставляем в запрос набор данных.
Выполняем запрос`

Comment: В вопросе, чётко и полно, описывайте, откуда и в каком виде поступает эта пачка бестенденциозных значений. А также - как именно устанавливается соответствие между этими значениями и ID обновляемых ими записей.

Comment: @ Akina Дополнил вопрос как мог... Цитирую `Данные поступают из парсера.  
Соответствие между значениями и id обновляемых записей устанавливается по порядку от указанного id в запросе..` Вроде нашёл решение, которое решает поставленную задачу. Если у вас не комментариев к нему, то наверное стоит оформить как ответ `SET `pole_2` = ELT(id-3,'zapis_4_izm_1','zapis_5_izm_2',...)
where id > 3`

Comment: Комментариев - нет. Но, извините, оформлять такой поход как решение что-то не хочется. Есть у меня пунктик - не люблю я ELT().

Comment: Если несложно, не могли бы как-нибудь кратко уточнить какие недостатки у ELT().

Comment: Поиск по его списку - это прямой перебор. Наихудший из методов поиска. Если аргументов больше 4-5 штук, лучше искать более вменяемые средства